# Python & Tkinter - Creating a menu within a def

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, sqlite

I'm trying to create a menu within one of my functions called "Core". This function gets called after the user has successfully logged into their account and I simply want them to make use of these menu's within the new window creates.

I can successfully create the menu onto the main base root, but I can't do it within the function which is being called as it gives me this error : " AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tk' "

This is the function itself : ( myGUI is the main root)

```
def Core():
myGUI.withdraw()
NewRoot = Toplevel(myGUI,
                   bg="powderblue")
NewRoot.geometry('800x500')
NewRoot.resizable(width=False, height=False)
```

It's being used within an "IF" loop, such as if user puts in the correct credentials then run the function above.

This is put within the IF loop.

```
myGUI.after(1000, Core)
```

The Problem: I want this menu to show within that function named "Core", but as I said before I get this error: "**AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tk'** "

```
# Creating a menu
mainMenu = Menu(Core)
Core.config(menu=mainMenu)
CoreContentMenu = Menu(mainMenu)
mainMenu.add_cascade(label="Support", menu=CoreContentMenu)
CoreContentMenu.add_command=Label("Frequent Asked Questions", command=lambda: GoFrame(FAQ))
```

I know that the error is here because I'm calling that function, but how can I make it work? Any help much appreciated!

```
mainMenu = Menu(CoreContent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use a class as the parent of a widget, in this line of code:

```
mainMenu = menu(Core)
```

You need to provide a valid widget, such as `NewRoot`.

Comment: Just realised my mistake.

Now I'm just getting a problem of adding the command within the menu.